# Potentially basic, is it possible to "unload" these pieces of unneeded code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please understand I know very little about these things, and so I was hoping you'd be able to help me. Essentially, I have a website and I'd like to make it lighter. Regrettably I cannot remove anything from the code directly - it's in a specific platform, and my access to the code is very limited - but I can add new code to the Head section, use Javascript and CSS.

Now, on to my problem. I noticed that some parts of the code are called upon, wasting some time and resources, but they're never really used at all. They usually go like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[link here]">
<link href='[link here]' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="8c92b238d59e992521843690-text/javascript" src="[like here]"></script>
```

I understand, if my basic knowledge of HTML is not wrong, that this essentially "imports" the content of those links, simplifying the code, but in some cases this is importing stuff that is never used at all. Is there any way to "unload" this before the person sees the page, so the resulting code is lighter? Maybe this is a completely absurd question, but please understand I know very little about these topics...

Comment: omit those lines from your html code and use javascript to detect the user agent, then write those things to <head>

Comment: @hanz, I cannot omit them. As stated above, those lines come in the actual code, and I cannot remove them directly. Otherwise, I naturally would...

Comment: There still no way to do thing like that since HTML = HTML, maybe try to use PHP

Comment: @Hanz, oh well, thanks!

Comment: Hanz is incorrect, and the suggestion to switch to PHP is nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about two different types of imported files, one CSS and the other JS.

It is possible to trim both of those down to just the portions needed by a particular page -- but in both cases you'd effectively be pre-processing the CSS or JS files to trim them down to just what is needed, rather than trying to do it in real time.

It's rare to do this by hand; usually you would handle this as part of the build process for generating the site.  If you're not already using tools like webpack or rollup, you would need to change your development process to take advantage of this sort of thing; it's generally not worth the effort for small-scale websites.

For CSS, one such tool is https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss

`webpack` or `rollup` will take care of the JS side of things; you can learn more about this by searching for "Tree Shaking" which is the common term for it.  One example: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: Seems interesting - I must admit I'm definitely a very newbie, and had trouble with some of your concepts - but ultimately I cannot change any of the coding at all. I can just add simple stuff to the CSS and Head portion of the page. But thank you for your help, okay? :)